# where I can find the little red dot image used in google map?

Tags: google-maps, marker

I am looking for the red dots showing [here](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=restaurant,%20dallas,%20tx&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=47.617464,93.076172&ie=UTF8&hq=restaurant,&hnear=Dallas,%20Texas&z=13)
I can find find plenty of push pins and shadows in various place. But cannot find this little dot....
Could someone help me?

Comment: [StackOveflow is not a link site or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661). This is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: @Ken White: hi, Ken. Thanks. Where should I go to ask this kind of questions. I see there are different exchange sits for different purposes.

Comment: user1441141's answer is good and should be accepted. It leads to a working copy of the red dot: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you just trying to copy out the style of the markers?

If you are using Chrome just press F12 for developer tools, go to resources, then choose Frames->Maps->Images.

All of the images are shown there along with their locations.

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_markers_A_J2.png

I believe those are what you are talking about?

If you are talking about the really tiny little red dots, they appear to be part of the map images themselves.

However, there is a little blue dot that looks to be exactly the same, https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png

Answer (score 46):

you dont need any image at all.

```js
var circle = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: .4,
    scale: 4.5,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 1
};

// stack exchange headquarters
var location = {lat: 40.7087507876002, lng: -74.00675015738136};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: location,
    zoom: 13,
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: circle, // set the icon here
});
```

Comment: How can we [make the circle in **gradient** color](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24575087/2700244)? Google says that they support all CSS3 colors for `fillColor`

Comment: @Jesse:  You can re-use the same `var` for all markers. 10k markers draw within 2 seconds (Oct 2016) on my Mac. If this is too slow, then you need to use Fusion tables.

Comment: Is there any way I can change circle border color on hover ?

Answer (score 26):

You can find a few here:

Red circle -https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752125_en_v0

Blue circle - https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752068_en_v0

Pink circle - https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752264_en_v0

Yellow circle - https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752063_en_v0

Green circle - https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752129_en_v0

Answer (score 3):

The dots come from this image : https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png (but they are easier to take from https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs2.png )

As far as copyright goes you should read the terms of services (http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html) if you plan on using them.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no static link to the little FusionTables red dot...

Also see https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_thread/thread/670a2af718afc97b?pli=1

Here are two links to lists of other static links
https://sites.google.com/site/gmapicons/home/ and
https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/

Alternative is to use this one
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png

That's what I am doing on my (test) map from Fusion Tables with Markerclusterer