# Google maps api dot marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markers

Currently I use a StyledMarker icon (the default bubble icon with custom colors), but I've seen that some sites use the more compact "dot" ([picture of dot marker](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kgIKcUsffkA/TspZ9QrlraI/AAAAAAAAAZc/yS5XiL__YAQ/s1600/Untitled1.png)). My question is if it is possbile to replace the default bubble marker with the dot using StyledMarker? If not, how can I solve it (by the way the solution must allow dynamic coloring of the dots)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but is it possible using open API:s? What I have done, well I have used google and stackoverflow to try to find a solution, I've read the reference material for StyledMarker and StyledIcon, and browsed through Googles sample/example library. Unfortunately no solution was found so that's why I posted this question :)

Answer (score 29):

You can declare the marker icon to be a [symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol) and customize it accordingly.

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: '#00F',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeColor: '#00A',
        strokeOpacity: 0.9,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        scale: 7
    }
});
```

You can play with each property to achieve the desired look.

[image]

If you want something more elaborate, I made (diclaimer: **It was me, as in I made it**) [a library to use icon fonts (such as font-awesome or material icons) to render images](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/ig_markerfactory) (using an auxiliar canvas, then getting its dataurl).

[image]

It's basically an image factory which you can use as

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: MarkerFactory.autoIcon({
        label: 'f1b9',
        font: 'FontAwesome',
        color: '#CC0000',
        fontsize: 20
    })
});
```

You can even omit the `font` property and it will render the literal text you pass it. I use this to enumerate the markers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The [StyledMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/) uses the (deprecated) [Chart Images API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons) for its icons.  It looks like that doesn't have a "measle"/dot in it (but [look for yourself](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#icon_list)).  In any case, from a quick look, it natively only supports these two:

- d_map_xpin_letter
- d_map_pin_letter

It is open source, so you can modify it to do whatever you want, but you might just have to use ["normal" custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons) to get "measles".

- [discussion of the Fusion Tables Users Group about how to find the URL of the measles](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/670a2af718afc97b/ee5d47b81168bcf1?lnk=gst&q=measle#ee5d47b81168bcf1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Even though the d_map_xpin_letter is not "measle" icon it could still work. I really like the possibility to add a star plus any character of ones liking, which help me solve some other problems. Thanks a lot (I would have uprated your answe but I'm still awaiting 15 rep points).

Answer (score 0):

You could draw yourself a dot using a customized circle: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

Comment: Thanks for your solution suggestion, but I don't like the design/look of the customized circles so the hunt continous :)

PS: I would have uprated your answer, but I'm still awaiting 15 rep points. DS

Comment: @user1736982 have a look at this questions answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11162740/1025391