# What is the url to google maps icons in this sample image?

Tags: google-maps

I am looking to use this icon for my markers in google maps. Does anyone know the url to these dots?
I do not see them listed here https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are called "measles".  The two I know of are:

- red circle: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png
- blue circle: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png

The question: [Google maps api dot marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857657/google-maps-api-dot-marker) discusses some other options.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. Load Google Maps and use your own Google API key
2. Adding different color markers of your choice
3. Wrapping into add marker function

The easiest way to test this is to use notepad++  (myMap.html)

Complete code here:   [change the color of Google map dots](http://%3Chttps://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-change-javascript-google-map-marker-color-8a72131d1207%3E)