# Plotting "Points" on Google Maps using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently loading an extensive set of points (latitude, longitude pairs) into a Google Map. My problem is that Google Maps plots these points as markers (the default kind), while I'd rather just have each point plotted as a "point" like in this map:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/atm/@54.0260702,-1.6780445,5z

rather than the marker as shown here (on Cimarron National Park):
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Great+Bend,+KS,+USA/Cimarron+National+Grassland,+242+Highway+56,+Elkhart,+KS+67950,+United+States/@37.7162446,-101.3770814,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x87a38bb5b59e293d:0x32155928d84780ee!2m2!1d-98.7648073!2d38.3644567!1m5!1m1!1s0x8708c3c3259cc53b:0x8109b72736458f11!2m2!1d-101.79!2d37.124167

Any Idea how this can be achieved through the Google Maps JavaScript API ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm currently loading points using GeoJSON into a Google Map."?  What does that code look like?  Are you using the [DataLayer in the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_geojson_data)?

Comment: I'm using the sample code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

The GeoJSON file only contains features of geometry type Point.

Comment: The code works without a hitch. The question was more of how one would use the marker style in my example URL (in the question) rather than the default "drop point" marker style

Comment: Edited the question so that there isn't any confusion around GeoJSON...

Comment: Doesn't my comment referencing the options for data layer styling answer that?  You set the icon property of the Point.  you still haven't posted any of _your_ code.  None of the google examples display "Points".

Comment: @gecodezip where would one set that ? in the GeoJSON ? If yes, what would be the value? I've searched quite a bit for documentation on what value to set (if any) and haven't been able to find it. Please help...

Comment: @geocodezip no it doesn't because the google documentation is horribly sparse on what to set for the option. Icon types available by default aren't easily listed. The documentation also doesn't make it clear as to how to handle a large number of points. Usually having access to a small marker like a dot would be useful. Anyway, To make it clear as to what I am looking for please see this image : http://imgur.com/bgfPqHh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty example (took something from the documentation and modified it):

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png"
  });
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_dataLayer_styledPoints.html)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a ton @geocodezip. My problem was I had no idea that the image was called measle.png. Where did you get this information from ? Is there some kind of directory / listing of images available for use that are given by google ?

Comment: It comes from years of watching the google maps API v2 and v3 discussion groups...

Comment: And this [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162740/where-i-can-find-the-little-red-dot-image-used-in-google-map)

Comment: Anyone knows why the "icon" property dosnt work in json? {geometry: {"icon": "https://www.domain.com/icon.png"} only via setStyle it works.