# How to set style for each point to different icon within a GeoJson file?

Tags: google-maps

I'm displaying several large lists of geojson files on google maps, using this call:

map.data.loadGeoJson()

within this lists, I have points of different categories, and I want to assign each category with a unique icon, so points would show up differently and user can tell which category a point is without clicking it.

I have all the info built into the geojson, but not sure what javascript call to make in the HTML page so I can set each point's style to the right icon. if anybody has some ideas to share would be great!

thx for your help!

Comment: Did you see [style options for point geometries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_options) in the documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom markers for points from a geoJson file with Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433084/custom-markers-for-points-from-a-geojson-file-with-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Data Layer: Dynamic styling?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic)`

Its not automatic, but user will not have to click.

```
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 8});
```

Comment: ok, thx for the hint. your idea is right but I don't want user to do anything - markers should load different icons based on features in the json file. google's sample code is close enough, I got it working.