# Create a marker with gradient fill instead of normal color - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am trying to get a dot like marker for Google Maps using `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` - in which I am successful.

```
var dotMarkerImage = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    scale: 7,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1
};
```

This successfully results in a blue circle, but I want a circle with a **gradient**.

[image]

Now [Google says in **Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) that we can use all CSS3 colors. How do I use `fillColor` to accept a gradient?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I would be interested in doing the same

Comment: Nopes. No answer yet