# Google Maps get a polyline with dots

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

In the Javascript Google Maps API v3 it is possible to draw a movable polyline. This is exactly the way I want my polyline to look, however, it doesn't need to be movable.

Now because it is movable it takes a lot more time to draw these polylines. 
I have to draw like 20 of these lines and hence up to 200 points. There is a noticeable lag compared to the normal time it takes to draw these lines.

Therefore my question is. Can I get a fast-drawing alternative for drawing a polyline that looks exactly as I have it right now? The image shows a bit more of what I'm looking for.

[image]

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some analysis, I found out there are a couple options.

The most flexible option is the option by MrUpsidedown. This shows a well-dotted line which seems to work rather well for smaller datasets. Furthermore, the added customizability with this option is preferred. However, the larger my dataset got the more performance improvement I had by using complex markers.

Comparison for around 2000 points:

- Circle approach took 3 seconds to render
- A custom symbol, drawing diamonds instead of circles took between 2 and 3 seconds.
- Complex markers, the dot image mentioned below, took less than 1 second.

The approach I took with the complex markers are the following:
I use the simple dot images of 9x9 pixels from google.

The images of the dots I used as markers can be found [at another stackoverflow topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336794/2277445)

The actual code I used to draw the point will be added at the bottom. Remind that I did not define the clickable region of the marker as I did not intend for it to be intractable. Hope it helps someone!

```
function drawMarkers(locations, color) {
    let colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'red'];
    if (colors.indexOf(color) < 0) {
        console.log("Color ", color, " not supported");
        return [];
    } else {
        let image = {
            url: 'img/dot-' + color + ".png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(6, 6),
            // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of our point.
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 3)
        };

        let allMarkers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            let location = locations[i];
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                zIndex: 5
            });
            allMarkers.push(marker);
        }
        return allMarkers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can. Use a Polyline and existing symbols. If that's not good enough, use [custom symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom).

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 15),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);


  // Create the polyline and add the symbol via the 'icons' property.

  var lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 30)
  ];

  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'orange',
    scale: 5
  };

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    strokeColor: 'orange',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '20px'
    }],
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this is not fast enough.

Comment: Not fast enough? I wonder how you get your data and how you render the Polylines and I am quite surprised that rendering hundreds (thousands?) of markers is quicker than rendering Polylines but we haven't seen your complete code. I have a website on which I render hundreds of Polylines, also with symbols (arrows) and it doesn't feel like it's lagging or anything.

Comment: I have a large table where I draw all the points on the hover action. So when going hovering over the table, to find the right (car)trajectory, I'm drawing thousands of points every second. Then when using your approach it is an annoying experience, sometimes I have to wait for seconds, which sorts of defeats the purpose. You could test it out yourself by drawing 5000 points on a hover event.